# Avoid split of text field to multiple pages

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a main report and in the main report a sub report called this:

```
<detail>
    <band height="50">
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="802" height="49" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
            <subreportParameter name="project_id">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{project_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["subs/Project_planned.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</detail>
```

There is a problem in the subreport because text fields in the detail band are split up on multiple pages what doesn't look very nice. Is there an option to prevent text fields from splitting up to multiple pages when using the property `isStretchWithOverflow`

Current code of a text field

```
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="555" y="0" width="99" height="21" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <box leftPadding="2">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{logic}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

Example on how it looks (sorry for the missing data):

[image: avoid split of text field on multiple pages]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes there is, but not on the text field. For the band the text field is in, you can set the Split Type to `Prevent`. if you set that on the Detail Band and the row needs to overflow to next page, it will move the entire row to the next page.

Comment: I have tried this in iReport but each time when I choose this option it changes back to `<default>` So I guess this wasn't possible in my situation but when I hardcoded this in the XML: `<band height="50" splitType="Prevent">` is still don't work... another suggestion?

Comment: I found the problem. I had setup the sub-report in the detail band of the main report. This occurs in several strange behavior. I now setup the subreport in a page footer and it seems to solve my problem, except that my main page header isn't shown now on every page

Comment: another comment: I solved it. Don't know how exactly but it seems to be fixed. Subreport still in detail band of mainreport. splitType of detail of subreport on `Prevent` and the following properties on the text-fields: `stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" height="21" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"`

Comment: A new problem. Maybe you also can help me with this. Now the column_count number of the entire moved row on the next page has still the next number of the previous page. Like 9,10 <page break> 11, 1, 2?

Comment: That from what I remember is not solvable. Essentially what is happening is that it places the last row, the counts are updated, then it can tell the row will not fit and moves it to the next page. You may want to open up another SO question asking for help, maybe someone will know the solution for that. Sorry.

Comment: I have changed it with adding a new variable and reset it by groups instead by page. For the moment this solves the problem. Thanks for your answer and comment. Jasper reports is great and limitless but sometimes a pain in the ass ;-)

Comment: can you please help me for this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851401/jasper-reports-page-break-increases-blank-space-at-bottom)