# jasper reports page break increases blank space at bottom

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports

I have a requirement to create a PDF page using jasper report. PDF is very huge so I need to divide it into three pages or multiple pages. Jasper studio has only **one** page to work. We can insert page break into the same jasper file.  Once I put two page break in designer mode (which will create three pages) then each page size will remain the same but creates unnecessary **blank** space. Attaching snapshot.[image]

How to resolve the blank space space ?

Answer (score 1):

To get the required Result (as shown in the right hand side images), you need to Decrease the band Height. It seems you have to half your current band size to get the desired Layout