# Jasper Report: Text field overlapping end of page

Tags: jasper-reports

Jasper report version 5.6.1 (due to a jdk 1.6 we MUSt use.....)
I have a report with a long text field in the bottom part of the page.

If i set Position type to "Fix Relative to Top" the text field will spread  over the end of the page and the start of the next page using space available at the end of the first page (so from my point of view this is a correct behaviour, or may be the behaviour i'm searching for)

If i set position to float, the text (and the caomponent) will be moved directly to next page, so some part of the first page is not used at all, and all the text is printed on next page.

I have the same behaviour with a fixed text and with a text with field (evaluated at runtime).

I have tried to set Strech type to:

1) Relative to tallest object

2) Relative to Band Height

All previous element in the report are set to float (static text and text field)

So i would like to use remaining space on first page to print some line of this text Field , and use second page to print remaining text. Available space on first page is variable due to variable height of previous component on first page, so i cannot use Fixed position for this field.

Any idea will be appreciated

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Field before this text field have variable height so i cannot use Fixed position for this text. But If i use float position for this textField entire textField will be put on the second page even if there is some space in the first page. In fact with "fix relative to top" (if previous data leave some space on page 1) text is partially printed in first page , and remaining text is printed on second page.

Comment: Do you have "Split type: prevent" on the band? It would seem, that the default behaviour should in fact be what you need, as for example shown by this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744920/avoid-split-of-text-field-to-multiple-pages

Comment: Good point i didn't know band could stretch. But the problem persist with this is the configuration (may be i'm missing something): 
Split type on band Stretch.  
Stretch type on text field Relative to Tallest Object.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you have to have this text field in the same band? If you move it to a new band you can then set it to a fixed position.

Comment: I have tried to put this textfield in another band but the result is the same. Text filed is entirely written in second page.(Added Jasper report version on question)