# JasperReport splits row textField with markup to multiple pages

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm facing with an issue in jasperreport, it is splitting textfield text to 2 pages as following:

1st page
[image: 1st page]
2nd page
[image: 2nd page]

The band settings

```
<band height="28" splitType="Prevent">
```

The textfield settings:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement key="item_key" style="style1" mode="Transparent" x="27" y="0" width="169" height="28" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" uuid="1cf875ae-a60b-4640-8c08-1454d669f7eb"/>
            <box topPadding="1" bottomPadding="2"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Top" markup="styled">
                <paragraph lineSpacing="Proportional" lineSpacingSize="0.6" leftIndent="3" rightIndent="3" spacingBefore="2"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{product}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

I'm using jasperreports-5.1.0 and java 1.7

I've checked solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744920/avoid-split-of-text-field-to-multiple-pages) but it didn't help..

**$V{product}** variable value is:

```
"<style size='10' vAlign='Top' isBold='true'>AA Test Product<style isBold='false'>\nAA Test Product"
+"\nAA Test Product"
+"\nAA Test Product"
+"\nAA Test Product</style></style>"
```

Comment: Does $V{product} contains all this 5 lines? Is this one multi-line value?

Comment: @AlexK I've edited my question and added $V{product} value